# Port of a queue, created from activation specification, not visible

Tags: queue, websphere, specifications, activation

We have an application, which contains message-driven bean.  In this case the activation specification connects to a JMS provider and opens the JMS destination queue , and then monitors it looking for messages. In the activation specification configuration, in the "provider endpoints", I provide host_name:59999. But after that when I restarted the WebSphere, I do not see this port listening. We have a test application, using ActiveMQConnectionFactory to create connection, and the url provided is:
tcp://host_name:59999. 
And when I start the application, I get java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Does any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: WebSphere has built in JMS provider, you dont need to use ActiveMQ. And activation specifications are not creating listener ports, they just bind MDB to the queue.If you want to use ActiveMQ, it must be running somewhere else, outside application server. When you will start ActiveMQ that server will open some ports, So you confused a lot.

Comment: Hello Gas, thanks a lot for the answer. Yes, I know that WebSphere has build in JMS provider and the applications are using it. Okay, it binds the MDB to the queue - I did not know that. We have tests, which are running independently and using ActiveMQ and I hoped, that when I specify the provider endpoint, I will be able to put messages in the queue.